# Passing flow through all nodes with min cost in networkx

Tags: python, networkx, network-flow

I'm using `NetworkX` to implement some papers.
(Actually, Networkx is not necessary. If there are better libraries for solving this problem, could you recommend it?)
And my graph looks like this image [Automated_Planar_Tracking_the_Waving_Bodies_of_Mul](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcqhV.jpg)

I gave positive weight to all nodes.
When I use `max_flow_min_cost(G, S, E)` function, the function returns paths like

```
[S, T1, T1', E], [S, T2, T2', E], [S, T3, T3', E], [S, T4, T4', E], [S, T5, T5', E], [S, T6, T6', E]
```

That's because these are paths with maximum flow.

But what I want is paths that pass flow through all nodes and whose total cost is minimum.
For example:

```
[S, T1, T1', T2, T2', E], [S, T5, T5', E], [S, T3, T3', T6, T6', E], [S, T4, T4', E]
```

So, I decided to use `min_cost_flow()` function. And it needs the demand of nodes. Of course, I can't use this method because I don't know how many paths will start from node 'S'.

Is there any solutions to solve my problem?

To sum up, I want some methods to find paths that go through all nodes and total cost of those is minimum.

My mother tongue is not English, and It might make you confused.
If you have any questions about this, please let me know.

Comment: Your problem sounds a lot like the traveling salesman problem (TSP). Are there any important differences that I am missing?

Comment: I think the answer of TSP is just one path. But I want to get several paths.
Actually, I noticed that I'd misunderstood about Min Cost Flow Algorithm. The algorithm needs the number of flows to solve a problem. And I didn't know the number of paths. That's why I couldn't the problem with MCF.